# Does the skin effect formula account for reflectivity?

Tags: electromagnetism, reflection

Does the skin depth formula $ \sqrt\frac{2}{wµσ}$ account for reflectivity?  I am doing an experiment for school centered around the skin effect. I found online that aluminium reflects about 95% of visible light, and was wondering if it would affect my results, given I use my local AM frequency of 234 kHz, which is a significantly lower frequency. My experiment is pretty simple. There are 3 parts to the experiment:

> An AM radio tuned to 234 kHz. This is a local frequency on which you can hear music.

> A modified LC cuiruit with an makeshift antenna tuned to oscillate at 234 kHz

> A box of wrapped in aluminium foil. I am using standard kitchen foil of a thickness of about 10 microns

### The method is as follows:

- I turn on the radio. (1)
- I power the tank circuit. (2)
- I use a ruler to record the distance at which my local radio is completely silenced by my tank circuit. (3)
- I place the tank circuit in the aluminium box and then repeat steps (2) and (3). (4)
- I repeat step 4, but the aluminium box is wrapped in an additional layer of aluminium foil

I already carried out this experiment, and I recieved suspicious values. Without Foil, I needed to be ~20 cm away from the radio. With 1 layer, I needed to be around ~7 cm away, and with 2 layers I needed to be about ~2.25 cm away. I need to know if the skin effect formula accounts for loss due to reflectivity to confirm my results. Also, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The skin effect formula assumes all of space is conductor, and there is an electromagnetic plane wave passing through. This formula described the EM field inside of the conductor, where ohms law applies. This is the field from the initial wave  plus the wave from the motion of electrons. The reflected wave is the new just the wave that moves beyond the boundary of the conductor. Therefore yes  it does take into account the reflected wave

Comment: However to determine via experiment if this formula is correct you'd probably need to also take into account the fact that this wave is NOT a plane wave. But infact one created from a source  and as such, experiences attenuation without the conductor present (hence why it stops reading without a conductor)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you by any chance have a source that could confirm this? I need it for my citations. By the way are there other experiments that can confirm the skin effect?

Comment: Other than the fact that I have derived it myself, no. However its derivation comes from maxwells equations when $$\vec{J} = \sigma \vec{E}$$ This however assumes $\rho = 0$ and is a plane wave in an infinite conductor. Solving maxwells equations by definition includes ALL fields present. This encompasses all sub fields. Incident wave and emmitted. However this formula doesn't exactly treat it as a wave incident on a boundary of a material, just a plane wave in a conductor.

Comment: @jensenpaull So just to confirm, if say a wave that was initially traveling in air comes in contact with a metal, at one skin depth it's intensity will be exactly 37% of the intensity it had in the air

Comment: I've posted another question about the validity of the assumptions made in the context of finite conductors, but assuming you aren't working about the buildup of charge on either side of the conductor, then yes. A PLANE wave incident will be 1/e the field strength of the indicent plane wave